# How to populate treeview using Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, treeview

Hi i am using dictionary to populate my treeview...

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>> management = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>>();
```

now management has the following values

```
ID  Name               Parent
1   Manager             0
2   Accountant          0
3   Assistant Manager   1
4   Branch Manager          1
5   Employee1           3
6   Employee3           3
7   Employee2           4
8   Accountant1         2
9   Accountant2             2
```

In the code behind DispalyTree() is the function that populate my treeview with dictionary vaules.. i know the below code is not complete.. i am just successful in displaying Manager and Accountant and i dont know how to populate its child nodes..

I have tried so much  but not able to do.. i am stuck with this for like one week.. Please help

```
public void DisplayTree()
        {
                TreeNode parentnode = new TreeNode();
                TreeBL l_bltree = new TreeBL();
                Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>> manage = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>>();
                manage = l_bltree.ChildTree();
                foreach (var kvp in manage)
                {
                    var innerDict = kvp.Value;
                    foreach (var innerKvp in innerDict)
                    {
                        parentnode = new TreeNode(innerKvp.Key);
                        if (innerKvp.Value == 0)
                        {
                            treeview.Nodes.Add(parentnode);
                        }
                    }              
               }

        }
```

Comment: what treeview WPF, WinForms??

Comment: asp.net web application

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the logic to build a tree view given a hierarchy.

The values are present in the `employees` param. Build an `Id->Employee map`, iterate through the values, find `parent` and add the `employee` as `parent`'s `child`. At the end you only want the `root` or its `children`.

```
// quick and dirty class
public class Employee
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public int ParentId;
    public IList<Employee> Children = new List<Employee>();
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Employee that;
        return
            obj != null
            && (that = obj as Employee) != null
            && Id == that.Id;
    }
}

// O(n) time, O(n) space for hashmap
public Employee BuildTreeView(IEnumerable<Employee> employees)
{
    var rootEmployee = new Employee() { Id = 0 };
    var IdToEmployeeMap = employees.ToDictionary(e => e.Id);
    IdToEmployeeMap[0] = rootEmployee;
    foreach (var employee in employees)
    {
        var parentEmployee = IdToEmployeeMap[employee.ParentId];
        parentEmployee.Children.Add(employee);
    }
    return rootEmployee; // or return rootEmployee.Children if interested in children
}
```